# T-SQL query result into variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, variables

I am trying to assign the result of a SQL query into a variable but running into issues.

Here is my query:

```
use db
SELECT name
,ID
,pID
,pName
,group
FROM mName as m
INNER JOIN pID_Check AS p ON m.ID= p.pID
WHERE p.pName NOT LIKE m.name
```

Query works fine however I'm trying to schedule it to run hourly via SQL Server Agent and email on results.
Most of the time the query will not return any data but in the event there are rows I need it to email out. 
Essentially need values of the row added to @results variable and email triggered only if @results not null

```
SET @sub = 'Subject' 
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
@profile_name = 'Profile',
@recipients = 'email@email.com;',
@body = @results,
@subject = @sub
```

Comment: The sp accepts an `@query` param to accomplish this, check the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to send the result set to a mail recipient - while that is possible, I'm not aware of being possible to stick into the body in the method which you have attempted.
It *can* be included as an attachment via another property of `SP_SEND_DBMAIL`. Please see your  example below, modified to include the result set as an attachment:

```
DECLARE @myquery varchar(max) = '
SELECT name
,ID
,pID
,pName
,group
FROM mName as m
INNER JOIN pID_Check AS p ON m.ID= p.pID
WHERE p.pName NOT LIKE m.name
'

SET @sub = 'Subject' 
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
@profile_name = 'Profile',
@recipients = 'email@email.com;',
@body = @results,
@subject = @sub,
@query = @myquery,
@attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
@query_attachment_filename= 'MyFileName.csv';
```

> All `SP_SEND_DBMAIL` properties can be seen here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql

Comment: If @attach_query_result_as_file is 0 the results are stuffed into the body.

Comment: @AlexK. I've never tried it that way, though you did get me rather curious. I'll give it a shot now. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: yup seems to be working great... now just gotta get a condition in that will skip emailing if the query results are empty... any thoughts on that?

Thanks again for the assit!

Comment: You're very welcome. As for the empty results, you can run a separate query to just get the count, once you have that, you can conditionally run the sp_send_dbmail statement (i.e. `IF(@recordamount > 0) begin....`)